# vagrant ssh uses wrong ssh executable

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have a vagrant box with CentOS7 running under KVM/QEMU (libvirt) on my Fedora 29 host. `vagrant up` works fine. `vagrant ssh` fails with:

```
/usr/share/vagrant/gems/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/lib/vagrant/util/safe_exec.rb:39:
in `exec': : Permission denied - /home/username/bin/sshPermission denied - /home/username/bin/ssh ( (Errno::EACCESErrno::EACCES)
```

The doc says: `Vagrant will attempt to use the local SSH client installed on the host machine.` However, `which ssh` correctly results in: `/usr/bin/ssh`. So why vagrant doesn't use it ?

The **directory!** `/home/username/bin/ssh` was included in the PATH env when the box was created and vagrant seems to have stored this information somewhere. Removing the directory from PATH didn't help. Only when I rename or remove the directory `vagrant ssh` does work.

Can anyone tell me where vagrant stored the wrong info ?

Edit: The Vagrantfile is nearly empty, only `config.vm.box` contained...

Comment: What's the content of your vragrant file?

Comment: @Andrei Lupuleasa: It's nearly empty. Problem happens with just 'config.vm.box' and nothing else ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I found the reason - seems to be a bug or strange behavior of the vagrant version 2.1.2 that I use:

I still had directory `/home/username/bin` in the PATH env. Vagrant seems to list all entries in all directories included in PATH to look for **ssh** and finds subdirectory `/home/username/bin/ssh` not realizing that this is a directory ...

After removing `/home/username/bin` the command `vagrant ssh` works as expected. So unless vagrant is improved I have to permanently rename my `/home/username/bin/ssh` directory ...